# Select 2 distinct columns in 4GL

Tags: sql, informix, 4gl

Needed for my 4gl program:
Let's say I have a table that holds a phone number and a name. There can be 2 people with the same phone number, or 2 names with 1 phone number. 
I need to select just 1 of each phone number in the table. 
I did:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone_number, last_name FROM table
```

The results will show 2 records. Even phone number is the same, since the names are different it is no longer unique. How can I get a unique phone number regardless of its *last_name*? (But I want to get the last name as well. I don't care which one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DISTINCT`, as you've noticed, will return rows that are distinct in their entirety.

It sounds like you're looking for something like `group by`. Essentially, `GROUP BY phone_number` will return one row for each phone number. Because you also want to get `last_name`, you'll need to instruct the database how you want it to be returned. You said you don't care which so you could simply write:

```
SELECT phone_number, MAX(last_name) as last_name
FROM table
GROUP BY phone_number
```

Informix also supports a `FIRST_VALUE` aggregate function although I've only used that in OLAP situations so I don't recall if it will work in this context.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care which last name, then try this out:

```
SELECT phone_number,
       MAX(last_name) AS last_name
FROM table
GROUP BY phone_number
```

Comment: Not going to downvote, but this question is tagged informix so I doubt TSQL will work.

Comment: It happens, I've done it too. MSSQL is my DB of choice